# Get application running on windows server even log off

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have developed a backup scheduler for mysql database using C#. I am not created it as `Windows Service` .I need to stay running the application on windows server even when I log off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) All you need is to set a schedule, user account and program to run.